# created a contract address using REMIX sent ETH but script didnt work

Tags: remix

I was following this direction on this link
https://umbot.substack.com/p/easy-to-use-arbitrage-mev-bot-for

Problem is I didn't realize when I was trying to fund this address I used the base network on coinbase to my Metamask wallet. Turns out its a layer 2. So Remix created ETH address but I sent it using my MM wallet on base network. So on etherscan the address shows that I created it. But it shows no ETH. On basecsan it shows the ETH balance I sent using MM. Using the same script on REMIX can I kill the address and thus it will send the base back to my MM wallet?

thanks

Comment: First of all that's a scam contract. I'm understanding your ETH is on base blockchain, and you didn't yet deploy your code there, right? If so you may be able to get it back if your nonce on base is lower than on ethereum.

Comment: its on Base blockchain, thanks for the heads up on the scam. Do you know how I can get it back?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find the transaction you used to deploy the contract on ethereum. Etherscan should show the nonce you used, let's call it `nonce_eth`.

Now go to your address on basescan, and find the nonce of the last made transaction, let's call it `nonce_base`. If `nonce_base < nonce_eth` then you can proceed, otherwise there's nothing you can do.

If `nonce_base = nonce_eth - 1`, immediately deploy this contract on base:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Retriever {
    constructor() {
        (msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    }
}
```

You can use remix as usual to do it. It should have deployed the contract at the same address as the one on ethereum, and automatically it should have sent the ETH to you.

If `nonce_base` is much lower than `nonce_eth`, you need to spam some transactions on base to increase the nonce. Careful to not overshoot. Then, when `nonce_base = nonce_eth - 1` you can deploy the contract.